# Cut a layout in the middle and insert another layout beneath

Tags: android, android-layout

thank you for taking the time to read and help,

My android application have 4 buttons in a Linear vertical layout in the buttom, after a while of usage, i want to cut the linear layout height in the middle and insert another layout that contains 4 buttons in the buttom, so there will be in the buttom 2 layout on top of each others

At the start of the application i want the buttons to appear at the picture shows (i already achieved this)

[image: Layout and buttons]

after sometime i want to change the old layout cut it's height in the middle and add another layout with another 4 buttons beneath it so it appears :

[image: Layout and buttons after]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

pls try the following `xml` layout.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">
        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:id="@+id/top_layout"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#00ff00">
            </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:id="@+id/bottom_layout"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#ff0000"
            android:visibility="visible">
            </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

I've hard-coded the height to `100dp`. You can set the value to a percentage height from your code within your Activity. ie: Calculate a specific height depending on the screen height.

I haven't used the buttons for demonstration purposes. You can change the visibility of the bottom layout to `gone` and see how the top layout grows. You can experiment with this code.

Comment: Okay i will try it out, please give some time I'm not at work today maybe tomorrow early :), thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Consider using the "`GONE`" attribute for a `View` object. E.g. `button.setVisibility(View.GONE);`

Basically, you can add all the buttons together and change the visibility status to "`GONE`" when you don't want that to be shown.

The main difference between "`GONE`" vs "`INVISIBLE`" is that, "`GONE`" will not take up the space for layout. However, `INVISIBLE` will still take the space when drawing the layout.

Comment: You mean i add all the buttons in the same layout?

Comment: I was assuming that you want to insert another set of buttons to the bottom and remove top buttons. Is that what you are trying to do?

Comment: No let me edit the question and explain using graphics

Comment: Yes, pls do. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can create two `LinearLayouts`

Assuming `LinearLayout1` is the one you want to show first.

put them in a relative layout and in `LinearLayout1` put `layout_above="+id/linearlayout2"` attribute.

`LinearLayout2` is set to gone by default in `xml` so `linearLayout1` will take the space in bottom and when you want to show the `LinearLayout` set it to Visible dynamically. got me?

Comment: Hello, i got what you mentioned but how I'm gonna split the layout in the middle exactly please note that the the layout size is dynamic you know depending on the screen..

Comment: u can put both `linearlayouts` in a parent `linearlayout` and assign them `layout_weight`